# How to copy django model object to self

Tags: python, django, copy

I have a custom photo/image serving application.  One of our optimizations is that the data for an image is stored on disk based on the MD5 of the image data.  I've written a custom `save()` method to handle taking the data from a `File` object and creating all the bits and pieces and fields necessary to create the actual database object.

At issue is the race condition that takes place when a the same image is uploaded at nearly the same time.  It is very possible that the `save()` method will be called by two different threads at the same time.

If the second thread discovers that the file exists we ignore that fact and continue processing.  While we do test to check if the file exists before writing it is NOT an error if two processes write the image data.  It will waste some cycles but the data will be the same as the md5 hash is the same.  We just test to avoid the waste of those cycles.

It is now time to write the actual object out to the database.  If we succeed then all is well and our object has been updated as needed by django's ORM.

If we failed due to an integrity error this means that the object came into existence between the time we were started.

When this happens we want to copy the contents of the actual saved object into `self` so that the caller has the impression that the `save()` worked.

```
    try:
        super(Photo,self).save(*args, **kwargs) # the "real" save()
    except IntegrityError:
        #
        # Looks like we were in a race condition.  We'll pull the 
        # record and copy it.
        photo = Photo.objects.get(hash=self.hash)
        # that fetch darn well should have worked.  If it didn't let the
        # error propagate so we can find and fix it.
        #
        # N.B. dangerious copy of fields from db object.
        #
        for field in photo._meta.get_all_field_names:
            exec('self.%s=photo.%s' % (field, field))
```

So the question is: Is this the best way to copy fields from a django DB object into another DB object which is self? I'm not sure if `copy()` or `deepcopy()` will even work or if it is the correct way to handle this situation.

Comment: You could raise a custom exception and let your application code deal with it (by requesting the object there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `deepcopy()` will work for this. But there is definitely a better way than `exec()`. Like this maybe:

```
 for field in photo._meta.get_all_field_names:
        setattr(self, field, getattr(photo, field))
```

Comment: `deepcopy()` will return an object which is then assigned.  I don't think `self=deepcopy(photo)` will work.